# Will using the include method in Javascript cause additional HTTP requests?

Tags: javascript, http, include, python-requests

I want to break up my index.js file into multiple files. For example, it would be nice to move all of my linked list implementation code into a linkedList.js file to keep things organized.

If I organize my code like this will it cause additional http requests? Is this something I need to worry about as far as load time?

Comment: There is no `include` method in JavaScript?

Comment: You can bundle your files into a single large one as part of your build process to generate the exact same index.js file as you currently have.